# Crosstab with Python with Sales data

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have this data:

```
Date        Month    ProductCategory        Sales
1/1/2009    2009-Jan    Clothing            1755
1/1/2009    2009-Jan    Grossery            524
1/1/2009    2009-Jan    Toys                936
2/1/2009    2009-Feb    Clothing            1729
2/1/2009    2009-Feb    Grossery            496
2/1/2009    2009-Feb    Toys
```

I want it as this table:

```
 Date      Month     Clothing Sales Grossery Sales  Toys Sales  Total Sales
 1/1/2009   2009-Jan    1755            524             936         3215
 2/1/2009   2009-Feb    1729            496                         2225
```

I tried this code:

```
train_cross =pd.crosstab([df_train.Date,df_train.Sales],
                          df_train.ProductCategory, margins=True)
                .rename_axis(None,1)
                .reset_index()train_cross
                .head()
```

I got these results:

```
  Date          Sales   Grossery    Toys    Clothing    All
  1/1/2009      524     1           0           0       1
  1/1/2009      936     0           1           0       1
  1/1/2009      1755    0           0           1       1
  2/1/2009      496     1           0           0       1
  2/1/2009      1729    0           0           1       1
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change first list to new index by columns `Date` and `Month`, add `Sales` to `values`, add aggregate function and specify column name of total column:

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=[df_train.Date,df_train.Month],
                 columns=df_train.ProductCategory, 
                 values=df_train.Sales, 
                 aggfunc='sum', 
                 margins=True,
                 margins_name='Total Sales')
print (df)
ProductCategory       Clothing  Grossery   Toys  Total Sales
Date        Month                                           
1/1/2009    2009-Jan    1755.0     524.0  936.0       3215.0
2/1/2009    2009-Feb    1729.0     496.0    0.0       2225.0
Total Sales             3484.0    1020.0  936.0       5440.0
```

If necessary remove last row and convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df = df.iloc[:-1].reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)

       Date     Month  Clothing  Grossery   Toys  Total Sales
0  1/1/2009  2009-Jan    1755.0     524.0  936.0       3215.0
1  2/1/2009  2009-Feb    1729.0     496.0    0.0       2225.0
```

Solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with no `margins`:

```
df = df_train.pivot_table(index=['Date','Month'], 
                          columns='ProductCategory', 
                          values='Sales', aggfunc='sum')
df['Total Sales'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
       Date     Month  Clothing  Grossery   Toys  Total Sales
0  1/1/2009  2009-Jan    1755.0     524.0  936.0       3215.0
1  2/1/2009  2009-Feb    1729.0     496.0    0.0       2225.0
```

And solution with `margins`:

```
df = df_train.pivot_table(index=['Date','Month'],
                          columns='ProductCategory', 
                          values='Sales', 
                          aggfunc='sum', 
                          margins=True,
                          margins_name='Total Sales')
print (df)
ProductCategory       Clothing  Grossery   Toys  Total Sales
Date        Month                                           
1/1/2009    2009-Jan    1755.0     524.0  936.0       3215.0
2/1/2009    2009-Feb    1729.0     496.0    0.0       2225.0
Total Sales             3484.0    1020.0  936.0       5440.0

df = df.iloc[:-1].reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: Didn't know you can do that with crosstab. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - Also it working with `pivot_table`, edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You ca use [`df.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df_new= df.pivot_table(index=['Date','Month'],columns='ProductCategory',values='Sales').\
reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)
df_new['Total_Sales']=df_new.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1)
print(df_new)

       Date     Month  Clothing  Grossery   Toys  Total_Sales
0  1/1/2009  2009-Jan    1755.0     524.0  936.0       3215.0
1  2/1/2009  2009-Feb    1729.0     496.0    NaN       2225.0
```